# Pycharm shows error on blocktrans templatetag

Tags: django, pycharm

`{% blocktrans trimmed %}` is showing error: `Invalid subtag for blocktrans is found. 'with', 'count' or 'and' expected`.

How `Pycharm` knows about templatetag's parameters? How can I fix this error?

I use old 2.7.3 version.

Comment: I have the same problem with Python3.5, Django1.11 and Pycharm Professional Edition 2019.1.3

Answer (score -1):

When you want to use "blocktrans", you should add this at the beginning of the file:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

AND at the settings.py:

```
USE_I18N = True
```

Comment: I didn't say that code is not compiled. Pycharm just doesn't recognize trimmed option.

Comment: I think this is not problem for python, It is problem for version of django. Pycharm recognizing tags is all from django.
I could rebuild the problem from my computer, I use python 2.7 too.

Comment: Pycharm can find blocktrans tag, by clicking on it. So Django version is not an issue.